# SwiftUI DatePicker Month Display Conundrum

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

Help! Depending on the selected date, the displayed date for a Swift DatePicker with CompactDatePickerStyle shows the month ('Mar'):

[image: Displaying Mar for month]

Or shows the month number ('3'):

[image: Displaying '3' for month]

I want all dates to display with the month name (abbreviated or full).

Here's the complete application in Xcode version 12.4:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var date: Date = Date()
    var body: some View {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $date)
                .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
                .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: It gets worse. Change from AM to PM for the date displayed as month number and the date then displays with date name.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm not displaying the time, but changing dates displays either the "month, day year" format or the m/d/yy format seemingly at random. Even the same date will display in either format at any time.

Comment: This same issues was raised on the [apple developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/675191) and does not have a working solution/fix yet.